# Set up drivers for owasp zap in selenium using java

Tags: java, security, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, zap

Hi I am trying to set up an automated framework using ZAP with my automated tests for a web application im tsting. But i cant seem to figure out how to start teh driver and open the website on chrome. Aparantly its quite easy and im trying to add

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setAutodetect(false);
proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.MANUAL);
proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8080")

DesiredCapabilites.setCapability(CapabilityType,PROXY.proxy);

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilties);
```

to my code but cant seem to figure out how this class is meant to be added to the tests, should this be @BeforeTest and how could i add it to my tests? Any help appreciated, I havent done any security testing before and have no idea how to do it.

Tried this also

```
    DesiredCapabilities dc;
    dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.CAPABILTIES, options);
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    driver.get("web-game-stage.sportdec.com");
```

Comment: What happens when you try to set the proxy? Does the connection work but ignore the proxy? Does it fail to connect? Are there any error messages? Can you check the proxy settings of one of the browsers you've started?

Comment: Here's a working proxy implementation that can be used with ZAP https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Selenium-WebDriver-3.0-Second-Edition/tree/530e1e84dddaa1f2ff953e67e399a73a3ceaab6a/Chapter08/Part%206 If you check that out and run `mvn clean verify -DproxyEnabled=true -DproxyHost=localhost -proxyPort=8080`  when you have ZAP running locally on port 8080 it should proxy everything correctly.  The book goes through it in more details

Comment: Basically when i run Zap with the proxy i can login/etc. But when i try this on selenium i cant get the port to go to 8080 or firefox so im trying to use chrome its the wrong port.  I just need a simple peice of code that allows me to start up the browser on firefox port 8080. Cant seem to do it at all.

Comment: Tried using that github but some things wont resolve for me, its all a bit of a nightmare

Answer (score 1):

> proxy.setHttpProxy("localhols:8080")

Typo in the host name: should be "localhost" ?

Comment: Apologies, typo there, wish that was the only issue i was having :D

Comment: No problem :) So have you got your selenium tests working without ZAP?

Comment: Yep they all work perfectly but im trying to set up a few simple ones using a 8080 proxy through firefox, my current setup is very complicated regarding starting browsers etc so i just want a simple way to start up the browser and run some end to end stuff. But I cant figure out how to do this. Ive added another attempt above but Firefox.CAPABILITIES wont work for me now

Comment: These are the settings we use for some of our tests in ZAP: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-hud/blob/develop/src/test/java/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/hud/ui/firefox/FirefoxUnitTest.java